# Unix field empty in the output query

Tags: unix, find, field, ksh

when i make this code:

```
ENDROW=""
while read ENDROW;
do
temp=${ENDROW##*#@;}          field1=`printf '"%s"\n' "${temp%%#@;*}"
#Here the insert >> ${sqlfile}
```

and look at the `${sqlfile}` output the fieldare empty... Seems that the code to find the field between the separators finished when it finds the first separator and then doesn't go on. Why?

Comment: I am missing a `done < name_of_file`... Can you also show some of your input so we can check it?

Comment: well, the `done < name_of_file` there is.. The structure of that file is something like `#@;field1#@;field2#@;field3#@;field4#@;field5` so my code would find the field1 then the field2 etc etc.. But results empty..

Comment: Besides the loop not being closed, there's also a half-open command substitution starting with `  `printf `, but never closed. Please improve the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input you indicate in the comments:

```
$ cat file
#@
field1#@
field2#@
field3#@
field4#@
field5
```

This could work:

```
while read ENDROW
do
  echo ${ENDROW%*#@}
done < file
```

That is, your substitution must be made with `%` (strip ... from back) rather than `##` (strip... from front).

#### Test

```
$ while read ENDROW; do echo ${ENDROW%*#@}; done < file

field1
field2
field3
field4
field5
```

#### In your case

```
#ENDROW="" #is not necessary
while read ENDROW;
do
  temp=${ENDROW%*#@}
  field1=$(printf '"%s"\n' "$temp")
#Here the insert >> ${sqlfile}
```

To read more about bash substitution:
- [wooledge.org - How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? How can I get a file without its extension, or get just a file's extension?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)
- [Shell Command Language - 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: so...it would replace this method ? `temp=${ENDROW##*#@;}`        `field1=`printf '"%s"\n' "${temp%%#@;*}"`

Comment: See muy lasted edited answer. I firstly indicated the way this subtitution should be done, then I updated your script.

Comment: seems go well :D the only problem now is the format of a date because the output is `printf:  Error converting 02.10.00.000000` is it correct this `'"%s"\n'` for a date field?

Comment: I just fixed a typo in `field` line. Check if it was this. Otherwise provide real data to see what's going on. `%s = seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` and should be fine if you give it a real data.

Comment: mmh now the values of fields are correct but it print the field with separators.`"@#field1@#field2`..wouldn't be `"field1 field2`?